# Understanding referencing other classes in java - null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm struggling understanding how work with java objects from other objects. I have 3 simple classes:
1) environment object

```
public class Environment {

protected String envName;

public Environment(String envName){
    this.envName = envName;
}

// get and set methods
public String getenvName(){
    return envName;
}

public void setenvName(String envName){
    this.envName = envName;
}

}
```

2) Class that will populate this object

```
public class FetchConfig {

Environment environment;

public FetchConfig() {
}

public void buildConfig() {
    environment.setenvName("Steve");
}
}
```

3) A class with main method with will work with my Environment objects:

```
public class WorkWithEnvironment {

private FetchConfig config;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException {

    WorkWithEnvironment w = new WorkWithEnvironment();
    w.setupConfig();
    w.readEnvNames();
}

private void setupConfig() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    config = new FetchConfig();
    config.buildConfig();
}

private void readEnvNames() {

    System.out.println("Environment name is: "
            + config.environment.getenvName());
}

}
```

But when I run it, I keep getting an NPE(NullPointerException) here -> environment.setenvName("Steve");

Comment: Your `FetchConfig` class has a `Environment` field. If you don't initialize it for each instance, it remains `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second class is trying to set values inside your Environment Class before instantiating it and so it is null when you try to assign a value to it.

```
public class FetchConfig {

Environment environment;

public FetchConfig() {
    environment = new Environment(null);
}

public void buildConfig() {
    environment.setenvName("Steve");
}
```

Comment: Thx all -- actually it needed to be "Environment = new Environment(null);  but I understand what I was doing incorrectly.

Comment: Edited my answer. Glad we could help.

Answer (score 1):

You've never told FetchConfig which Environment to use. I think you meant to have `environment = new Environment();` or similar in FetchConfig's default constructor.

You could also initialize the variable environment with a similar line in the buildConfig method.